# conky execpi command only reads first 256 bytes of output

Tags: linux, conky

I'm trying to set up conky with conkyForecastWU using a `.conkyForecast.template`. I include the forecast command as follows in my `.conkyrc`:

```
${execpi 1800 conkyForecastWU --template=~/.conkyForecast.template}
```

But when I start `conky` I see the following errors appearing every second:

```
Conky: Unable to load image '/tmp/'
```

The `conkyForecastWU`-command from above generates the following output:

```
${font Raleway-10:weight=thin}
${image /tmp/.conkyForecastWU-WI-Clear.gif -p 40,1000 -s 60x60}
${image /tmp/.conkyForecastWU-WI-Chance-Of-Rain.gif -p 123,1010 -s 40x40}
${image /tmp/.conkyForecastWU-WI-Partly-Cloudy.gif -p 177,1010 -s 40x40}
${image /tmp/.conkyForecastWU-WI-Partly-Cloudy.gif -p 231,1010 -s 40x40}
${image /tmp/.conkyForecastWU-WI-Chance-Of-Rain.gif -p 285,1010 -s 40x40}
${image /tmp/.conkyForecastWU-WI-Mostly-Cloudy.gif -p 339,1010 -s 40x40}
${image /tmp/.conkyForecastWU-WI-Partly-Cloudy.gif -p 393,1010 -s 40x40}
```

When I add a space at the end of the first line, the error message ends with `'/tmp'`, so conky only reads this part of the output, which is exactly 256 bytes long:

```
${font Raleway-10:weight=thin}
${image /tmp/.conkyForecastWU-WI-Clear.gif -p 40,1000 -s 60x60}
${image /tmp/.conkyForecastWU-WI-Chance-Of-Rain.gif -p 123,1010 -s 40x40}
${image /tmp/.conkyForecastWU-WI-Partly-Cloudy.gif -p 177,1010 -s 40x40}
${image /tmp/
```

But what's wrong? Seems to be a buffering issue when reading the output, but how can I tell conky to read more than 256 bytes?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14785/conky-buffer-too-small

After setting

```
text_buffer_size 1024
```

the problem was solved.